# Postgres join on min(*) + group by super slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-aurora

This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id AS user_id, messaged_date
FROM users
         JOIN (
           SELECT MIN(message_date) AS messaged_date,
                user_id
           FROM messages
           GROUP BY user_id
     ) messages_join ON user.id = messages_join.user_id
WHERE (user.client_id IN ('1234')
    AND user.status IN ('statusA')
);
```

1. `messages` table has two colums -> `user_id` and `messaged_date`. I have an index on both as well as a multicolumn index `(user_id, messaged_data asc nulls last)`
2. `messages` table is huge. About 50Gb in size.
3. The query takes ages (5+ mins) to run.
4. If I remove the join, it returns in under 1s.
5. I want one row per `user_id`

What can I do to make the query perform faster? Clearly, the join on `min` plus `group_by` is the cause. (`EXPLAIN` confirms this.)

I have tried the [loose index scan, aka a "skip scan"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170860/how-to-optimize-min-max-queries-for-large-tables-on-postgresql) which performs well by itself, but does not help when its results are joined.

Comment: What are you tring to do?

Comment: Get the earliest date that a user was messaged, filtered on `client_id` and `status`

Comment: That is not what your query does...

Comment: My bad, I added the missing `messaged_date` to the select clause

Answer (score 2):

This addresses the original version of the question.

The subquery is very strange.  It looks like you just want `exists`:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id
FROM users u
WHERE u.client_id IN ('1234') AND
      u.status IN ('statusA') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM messages m
              WHERE m.user_id = u.id
             );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `messages(user_id)`.

Comment: This does not collapse the messages to the earliest message, which `min(messaged_date)` does.

Comment: @ritratt . . . You are not using the earliest date.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I added the column to the select.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (users.id)
       users.id AS user_id,
       messages.message_date AS messaged
FROM users
   JOIN messages
      ON users.id = messages.user_id
WHERE users.client_id = '1234'
  AND users.status = 'statusA'
ORDER BY users.id, message.message_date;
```

Indexes that can speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON users (client_id, status);
CREATE INDEX ON messages (user_id);
```

Comment: This looks promising but it still takes very long

Comment: I fixed some bugs in my answer and added two index suggestions.

Comment: I already have the `messages (user_id)` index. I added the `users (client_id, status)` index also. But it still takes more than 5 minutes.

Comment: You cannot get more unless you add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.